# Проброс аутентификации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Прошу совет и/или пример как реализовать проброс авторизации:
есть webapi сервис авторизации (выдающий bearer token),webapi  сервис данных (реализующий взаимодействие с БД)  ну и MVC проект, который является клиентом.

Чего хочу:
получив токен от сервиса авторизации(он уже есть),

1) как-то впихнуть его в клиент, чтобы на клиенте можно было пользоватся 
HttpContext.User.Identity  и атрибутом авторизации ([Authorize(Roles="User,Admin")])

2) получив от клиента запрос на сервисе данных, каким-то образом заставить сервис данных постучать в сервис авторизации и спросить какими полномочиями обладает клиент

Comment: первый пункт, а почему Identity впихнуть на клиенте, это ведь должно быть на сервере?

Comment: потому, что на клиенте в зависимости от того, какие у пользователя роли и авторизован ли он вообще, нужно отдавать определённый контент

Comment: клиент имеет какой-то контент? Я к чему, мы защищаем контект на стороне сервера, соответственно Identity выставляются и проверяются на сервере(указанные аттрибуты - это .NET атрибуты на методы сервера).

Comment: asp mvc приложения тоже могут использовать эти атрибуты. webapi - по сути та же картошка, только в профиль.

клиент генерирует страницу с помощью razor. и в нём в зависимости от роли  некоторые кнопочки могут отрисовываться, а могут и нет, при этом никакого обращения к сервису данных не требуется.

но и когда например в список товаров вносится новая запись, сервис данных должен спрашивать у сервиса авторизации "есть ли у меня права"